# Correct usage of the auxiliary verb in a complexed sentence

Tags: grammar

"Since my expected position is a Payroll executive, there ***will be*** some professional qualifications ***will be*** expected for applying that."

in here, I have used 'Will be' at two places, So Please clarify me if it is wrong or just fine.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like you are missing a _which_ there.

Answer (score 1):

The second " will be" is wrong. Need to replace " will be" to " which are" or just simply remove the second " will be".

Comment: Thanks friend, I got it....!